# Drawer + Picasso тормозит выезжающий навигационный вид

Tags: java, android

Использую пикассо для загрузки изображений в навигационный вид. При загрузке изображений из инета, navigationview быстро подхватывает картинку подставляет куда нужно. Нет проблем. А вот если я указываю выбор картинки из локального хранилища, то бишь с СД-карты, то navigationview начинает тормозить. Даже выдает такую ошибку.

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 22MB until OOM"
```

Получается, что беда с памятью. Подскажите, как решить проблему?

Comment: Вы указываете прямую ссылку, Без использования Picasso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да у Вас по логу `OOM`, если вы указываете локальную картинку без использования различный `лоадеров`, то это вполне реально. 
Грузите изображения так же, через `Picasso`, но используйте `resize`.
Ниже ссылка на пример, как это сделать. Это избавит Вас и от ООМ и от тормазов.

https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Comment: Спасибо за инфу. Тогда такой вопрос - а как с помощью ресайза определять размер картинки на различных устройствах? Ведь там ресайз указан в пикселях

Comment: Берите высоту и ширину ImageView, как только они станут известны, можете их подставить.

Comment: Resize помог - все тормоза ушли, но теперь (испробовав все параметры из указанной статьи) имидж получается размытым. Без ресайза имидж был четким. Так и должно быть или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Смотря какой размер берете =) Если вы берете их в пиксилях не из imageView.getHeight(), а равнозначную  цифру (К примеру в xml image view имеет размер высота  126dp а ширина 320dp) и вы такие же цифры указываете для resize(126, 320), тогда на экранах с высокой плотностью она будет размыта, если вы указываете подобными цифрами, вам нужно перевести цифры указанные в resize в пиксели. (dpToPx) http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410076/2667883